# show status pending to approve

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i try this query to show upload documents ..this query works

```
CREATE PROCEDURE b
AS
SELECT  di.DocID, 
        di.DocName, 
        di.Uploadfile, 
        dt.DocType,
        d.DepType, 
        at.ApproveType
FROM    DocumentInfo di
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        DocType dt ON dt.DocTypeID = di.DocTypeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Department d ON d.DepID = di.DepID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ApproveType at ON at.ApproveID = di.ApproveID 
   AND  at.ApproveID = 3
```

i create a approval table in this
approval table
docid
approveid
approveby
 admin approve/reject documents and the data goes to this table i.e

```
docid approveid approveby
  1     2      john
```

it works but in above query i want to show when user upload any document then its status display as pending then when admin approve/reject documents then status change to approve/reject.. how i done this ..
this is form where admin approve/reject documents and data goes to approval table and it works 
[admin approve/reject documents](http://i42.tinypic.com/2wd1uzb.png)

jwhere as this is form where i show status
[show status here (image)](http://i43.tinypic.com/15psbjm.png%5B%5E%5D)

any solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Is it a join to the approval table you are missing? Can you please try cleaning up the language a bit so that the problem is easier to understand?

Comment: have you see pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean now. You want to show Pending if a matching row is missing in the Approval table, and Approved/Not approved (from approveid) if a matching row exists?

See if this helps:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE b
AS
SELECT  di.DocID, 
        di.DocName, 
        di.Uploadfile, 
        dt.DocType,
        d.DepType, 
        at.ApproveType
FROM    DocumentInfo di
    JOIN
        DocType dt ON dt.DocTypeID = di.DocTypeID
    JOIN 
        Department d ON d.DepID = di.DepID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Approval a ON a.DocID = di.DocID
    JOIN
        ApproveType at ON at.ApproveID = ISNULL(a.Approveid, 3)
```

a.ApproveID will be null if the document is missing in the Approval table. The ISNULL function returns 3 if ApproveID is null, or the actual value if it's not null.

I also removed outer joins you probably don't need. The outer join against Approval is required though.

Comment: thanku so much .....@dag...